# Accessing networked computers using C#

Tags: c#, workgroup

I have built an application with a tree view showing the file structure of the server the application is running on. I want to be able to include in the tree the file structure of machines connected through the network.

Something like [this](http://www.vb123.com.au/toolbox/04_docs/op2.gif) but with multiple workgroups.

The only example I have found which is similar so far is [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ListNetworkComputers.aspx) example which simply lists machines connected through the network, whereas I want access to the folders within them.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get an array of directory names (`String[]`) assuming the process is running as an account with access to the share:

```
var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"\\HOSTNAME\ShareName\");
```

You can use a similar method to bind the entries to a `TreeView`. You'd need to update your question to include whatever UI code you're using.